# Threading in java - Party simulation

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

For an assignment for varsity work, we need to work with threads. These threads are depicted as dots which are people at a party. There are rules to the party. i.e. people need to wait until everyone has been created before starting the party and being allowed to enter. Another rule is that only one person may enter the party at a time through the door. I have synchronized this block of code, but for some reason, when running the simulation the people sometimes walk on each other when entering, it doesn't happen all the time, it may happen once or not at all in a simulation. This is frustrating as I have tried anything and everything to stop it!

The are some more rules, which might help your understanding.

-Everyone has to go to the bar and get a drink before they are allowed to leave.

-People can only leave via the exit blocks

Here is the code for people entering the party (class:person mover, run method)

```
public void run()
{

    try {
        barrier.await();
        sleep(rand.nextInt(10000)); //time till arriving at party
        counter.personArrived(); //add to counter


        synchronized (grid.getEntranceBlock())
        {
            GridBlock firstBlock = grid.getEntranceBlock(); //enter through entrance

            synchronized (firstBlock)
            {
                assert (firstBlock == null);
                firstBlock.waitBlock();
                thisPerson.initBlock(firstBlock);
                counter.personEntered();
                sleep(thisPerson.getSpeed());
                firstBlock.notifyAll();
            }//end first block synchronisatioin

            grid.getEntranceBlock().notifyAll();
        }//end gridblock sync

    } catch (Exception e1)
    {
        done=true;
    }

    while ((!done)&&(thisPerson.inRoom())) {    
        try
        {
            if (thisPerson.thirsty())
            {
                if (thisPerson.atRefreshmentStation())
                {
                    sleep(thisPerson.getSpeed()*4);//drinking for a while
                    thisPerson.drink();
                }
                else headForRefreshments();
            }
            else if (thisPerson.atExit())
            {
                thisPerson.leave();
            } 
            else
            {
                mingle();
            }
            sleep(thisPerson.getSpeed());
        }           

        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Thread "+this.ID + "interrrupted."); 
            done=true;
        } 
    }
    counter.personLeft(); //add to counter

}
```

Methods used:from different classes

class:RoomGrid

```
public synchronized GridBlock getEntranceBlock() 
{
    return Blocks[getMaxX()/2][0];
}





public synchronized GridBlock getBlock(int i, int j) 
{  
    //return block associated with grid position
    if (!inGrid(i,j)) 
         return null;
    return Blocks[i][j];
}
```

class: GridBlock

```
public  void waitBlock()  
{
    occupied=true;
}
```

class: Person

```
public synchronized void initBlock(GridBlock b) 
{
    currentBlock=b;
    X=currentBlock.getX();      
    Y=currentBlock.getY();
    inRoom=true;
}
```

Comment: `assert (firstBlock == null);`? Show your actual code.

Comment: Thank you :) But the problem has been fixed